# VS Code Intellisense for javascript not giving method suggestions

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, javascript-intellisense

I've been searching for an answer to this with no luck. VSCode offers some suggestions like in this example:

[image]

However, many suggestions do not show up. For example, when passing an event there is no suggestion for e.preventDefault, or any of the associated methods or data that will accompany an event.

In the tutorial I'm watching I don't know if they are using 'javascript completions' with Sublime or if they have an extension in VSCode, but if it's possible to do this with Visual Studio I would really like to continue using it.

Example from the tutorial below:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

VS Code can infer the types in many cases but sometimes you need to explicitly annotate them using jsdocs ([more info](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/javascript#_intellisense)).

In the `addItem` case, add a `@param` jsdoc annotation stating that `e` is an `Event`:

```
/**
 * @param {Event} e
 */
function addItem(e) { ... }
```

This is not required if you use an inline function for `addEventListener` because we can infer the type in that case:

```
obj.addEventListerner('submit', function(e) { ... })
```

Comment: Annotate all the methods? That's not even a serious suggestion. It's not because it cannot infer the type it's because the buggy half-baked plug-in does not work.

Comment: @RickO'Shea Your comment doesn't contribute anything. If you're going to complain, at least propose an alternative